# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' What is wrong in my code?

Tags: python

I got an error,AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'.I wrote codes in views.py

```
import os
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
import random

path = Path(__file__).parent
path /= "../../image1"

path1 = Path(__file__).parent
path1 /= "../../image2"

index_list =[]
for i in path.iterdir():
  i = str(i)
  print(i)
  if i.split(".")[-1].lower() in {"jpeg", "jpg", "png"}:
      list_img = cv2.imread(i)
      index_list.append(list_img)

num = 0
for j in path.iterdir():
  j = str(j)
  if j.split(".")[-1].lower() in {"jpeg", "jpg", "png"}:
        img = cv2.imread(j)
        num += 1

        random_int = random.randint(0, 9)
        index = index_list[random_int]
        height1 = index.shape[0]
        width1 = index.shape[1]
        print(height1)
        print(width1)
```

When I run this code,I got an error,    height1 = index.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'  .
In image1's folder,5 images are in there like photo1,photo2,photo3,photo4,photo5.I debuted this program,so I found photo3 causes this error,and I deleted photo3 from image1's folder.And I run this program again,photo2 causes this error.I really cannot understand why this error happens.I think maybe wrong path of the folder causes this error,but it is wrong.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `index` is `None`, which means that one or more items in `index_list` is `None`. This is probably because an image you opened with `cv2.imread()` earlier couldn't be found. As [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) notes, "Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but `print img` will give you `None`."

This is an error condition that you should test for *when it might have occurred* and, when it is found, *handle* (say, by displaying an error message and refraining from saving it for further processing). Do not, as you are doing now, ignore the error condition and allow the problem to propagate to later code, where you then have to figure out how `index` got to be `None`. If you had written even the most basic error handling, your question would be "why isn't `cvv.imread()` finding my image files?" rather than "why is Python complaining about a `NoneType` object?"

To detect errors, you could use something like this:

```
list_img = cv2.imread(i)
if list_img is None:
    print("Couldn't open file %s" % i)
else:
    index_list.append(list_img)
```

This will at least tell if you if's trying to open the files that you think it is. My guess is that it's not finding any of your files, because you're getting a list of files from a directory that's not the working directory, but you're not specifying that directory name when opening the files. Therefore it's looking for the files in the working directory, where they're not.

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur detecting errors code,but error happens `if list_img: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` .How should I fix this?

Comment: I swapped it around to check for `None` explicitly (sorry, forgot NumPy's nonstandard behavior wrt the Boolean value of containers).